# What items can you get from goodie bags?

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

With the halloween update, goodie bags were added to the game. I wonder what I can get from them.

What items can one get from goodie bags?

Comment: goodie bags were not just added to the game, they've been there for a while, it's just that it only takes effect during the halloween season. You can change your system time to halloween or christmas whenever you want in order to get access to the special events.

Answer (score 4):

There are 30 items that you can get from Goodie Bags:

- Unlucky Yarn
- Bat Hook
- Rotten Egg (10-40)
- Bitter Harvest
- Blood Moon Countess
- Hallow's Eve
- Jacking Skeletron
- Morbid Curiosity
- Cat Ears
- Creeper costume
- Pumpkin costume
- Space Creature costume
- Cat costume
- Karate Tortoise costume
- Fox costume
- Witch costume
- Vampire costume
- Leprechaun costume
- Robot costume
- Princess costume
- Treasure Hunter costume
- Wolf costume
- Unicorn costume
- Reaper costume
- Pixie costume
- Bride of Frankenstein costume
- Ghost costume

[Source: wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Goodie_Bag)